# How to stop the "friendship anniversary" notifications on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I regularly receive notifications in Facebook Messenger about the anniversary of my friendship (*amiversaire* in the French version) with a friend. Messages like

> you have been friends with [friend] since [date]

(my own translation from French). The message also appears in the private chat with that friend. This is annoying since I have many friends and I am receiving daily a lot of undesired notifications.

**Is there a way to turn off these notifications?**

I tried to google it but all results are about notifications of friends' anniversary, which I want to keep.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I miss legit Messenger messages because 90% of the notifications I receive are this kind of "friendship anniversary" crap.

Comment: @Sébastien: yes, they are annoying. I haven't done anything but I don't receive them anymore. Maybe, if you ignore them for a while, Facebook undestands you are not interested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick:

First, you need to switch to "Classic Facebook", as the "new Facebook" (as of May 2020) does not have the option.

Then, go to https://www.facebook.com/memories/ and disable notifications:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2ITpKJK.png]