# Prevent "Friendversary" notifications in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, friends, facebook-friends

I rarely use Facebook Messenger. But I am *often* given red Messenger badge "unread message" notifications for **friendship anniversaries**.

[image: unread friendversary]

The notification causes a red Messenger badge, which is very annoying as you think you are getting a real message. If you are using a mobile app, you also cannot clear the red Messenger badge without installing the separate Facebook Messenger app.

The title of these messages is:

> You and FRIEND_NAME are celebrating X years of friendship on Facebook

Opening the message in your inbox displays the message:

> Happy Friendversary with FRIEND_NAME
>
> You became friends on Facebook X years ago.
>
> See Friendship

---

[image: Happy Friendversary]

---

This notification is not a "Facebook Memories" feature, nor a Friendversary Video. It is not in the Timeline. It seems to be a "growth hack" designed to drive usage of Facebook Messenger.

How do I prevent these Friendversary messages from showing up in my inbox and causing the Messenger badge to turn red due to unread messages?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to stop the "friendship anniversary" notifications on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137066/how-to-stop-the-friendship-anniversary-notifications-on-facebook)?